# How to convert .mpub to pdf

Tags: convert, ebooks

Currently I have an mpub (Mobcast Mobile Optimized ePub Book) file which I would like to convert to pdf.

Calibre does not support the mpub extension type https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html

I am looking for a workaround as I have not been able to find any at the moment.

**File contents include**

[image]

**References [updated]**

1. [file-extensions.org: convert-mpub-to-pdf](https://www.file-extensions.org/convert-mpub-to-pdf)
2. [file-extensions.org: mpub-file-extension](https://www.file-extensions.org/mpub-file-extension)
3. [wiki.mobileread: Mpub](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Mpub)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is going to be one heck of a challenge. The .mpub format was created as a direct competitor to .epub by Mobcast and it has pretty much evaporated. Not even Mobcast supports it anymore. You may have to do a bit of manual work to get the .json data out into a readable format ... so long as that .pem isn't indicative of DRM that may point to servers that no longer exist ...